# Keyboard and Mouse Not working after boot (Arch-Linux)

Tags: x11, keyboard, mouse

This problem is really annoying as my keyboard and mouse won't work when the system is first booted.

I can't even enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go into terminal too. The only option is to restart and after restarting several times it works.

This problem is not only with Arch Linux but also with Manjaro, Antegros and other arch based linux.

USB Mouse and TouchScreen works though.

My laptop is acer Spin with 8GB Ram. Is this problem with X11.

Also the `/etc/X11/x.config.d/` directory is empty there is no config file inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Install the USB utilities package from for arch linux

```
pacman -Sy usbutils
```